# How to rewind a CSV by one line?

Tags: php, csv

I am looping through a CSV to get product data. There are some lines that are variants of products and have a line of their own, e.g.:

```
sku, base_sku, name, desc, attribute
, 123, "product name", "long description here", Colour
abc,123,,,Red
xyz,123,,,Blue
novar,novar,"No variant product", "description here",
```

The main product has a `base_sku`. All variants will have a specific sku, linked to a product by the `base_sku`. If a product has no variants, then the product has a sku and base_sku of the same value.

Anyway, I am looping through the CSV using:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

Then I'm doing a check for variants and doing another while loop to get all variants:

```
while (($varient = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
```

During this `while` loop I am checking if the `sku` and `base_sku` are the same, and if they are break out of the `while` loop. Now I want to rewind the file pointer by one line so that when the first `while` loops it will read the correct line.

At the moment I have tried:

```
fseek($handle,-1,SEEK_CUR);
```

Which, I misunderstood at the time, is sending the file pointer back per character, not per line.

**How do I get the file pointer to go back by one line?**

Comment: you can use function to convert and check file pointers
function csvToArray($file) {
    $delimiter = ',';
    $csv_file = new SplFileObject($file);
    $csv_file->setFlags(SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);
    $csv_file->setCsvControl($delimiter);

    /**
     * Process each line from the CSV file
     */
    while ($csv_file->current() !== false) {
        $count++;
        $lines[] = trim($csv_file->current());
        $csv_file->next();
    }

    foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
        $lines[$key] = explode(';', $value);
    }
    return $lines;
}

Comment: There is no easy way. Save the line in a variable and retrieve it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to do this so I have converted my code a little to work with arrays:

```php
$rows = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] = $data;
}

foreach ($rows as $data) {
```

Then I use the array functions [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) and [`prev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can save the previous position with the function ftell()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php
then you can go back to that position
with the function fseek()

so you code would look something like this

```
$prev_line=null;

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $prev_line=ftell($handle);
  while (($varient = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    if($varient['sku']==$varient['base_sku']){
        fseek($handle, $prev_line, SEEK_SET);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

so your pointer will be in the previous location as it was before it entered the second while loop

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. The result was only the last character of the current line - fgetcsv returning a single element array containing the last character :(

Comment: can you try moving the $prev_line=ftell($handle); at the end of 1st loop and inside the second loop check if(is_null($prev_line)){ rewind($handle) }else{fseek($handle, $prev_line, SEEK_SET); } break;